# nosetests executing methods that not start with test

Tags: python, nosetests

I wrote a nosetest class to test a particular method - test_method()

WHen I run this module I noticed nosetests ran the other methods as we well - create_test_private_method.

I thought nosetests will test only methods that starts with test_.

```
import unittest

class test(unittest.TestCase):

    def create_test_private_method(self):
        self.assertEqual(1,1)


    def test_method(self):
        self.assertEqual(2,2)
```

Output:

```
create_test_private_method (nosetest.test) ... ok
test_method (nosetest.test) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.009s

OK
```

Comment: Have you read http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/finding_tests.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [nosetests docs](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/man.html#description):

> Any python source file, directory or package that matches the testMatch regular expression (by default: (?:^|[b_.-])[Tt]est) will be collected as a test (or source for collection of tests).

To avoid such a behavior you can

- rename your methods
- decorate your methods with the [`nose.tools.nottest` decorator](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html#nose.tools.nottest) (as Oleksiy pointed out)
- define a [custom tests selector](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/doc_tests/test_selector_plugin/selector_plugin.html).

Comment: there is also `nose.tools.nottest` decorator http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html#nose.tools.nottest